# Function that passes a key value and returns a list of names from a Data frame, R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a little rusty working with R and am more familiar with pandas, but I can't think of how the syntax of this would go.  Is there a way to build a function that passes in a key value into a data frame, and returns a list of names associated with that key value?

Something akin too...

```
#Example df Data
Name    JobID
Ted     1
Bill    1
Frank   2
Ox      3

FindName <- function(x){
  value = df.loc[(df['JobID'] == x), 'Name']
  outList = value.iloc[0]
  return outList

NameList <- FindName(df$JobID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that uses the mtcars built in dataset to return the elements in vector/column `x` (for you this would be `Name`) where the elements in vector/column `y` (for you this would be `JobID`) match the value `v` (for you this would be `1`).

```
findName <- function(x, y, v) {
  x[y == v]
}

findName(rownames(mtcars), mtcars$cyl, 4)
```

The reality is that you really wouldn't need to do this as a function, it would be unnecessary. It would be less work to just write directly as and when needed `df$Name[df$JobID == 1]`. Using your data, the above solutions return:

```
> findName(df1$Name, df1$JobID, 1)
[1] Ted  Bill
Levels: Bill Frank Ox Ted
> df1$Name[df1$JobID == 1]
[1] Ted  Bill
Levels: Bill Frank Ox Ted
```

The way these are working is that they are performing a *linear search* to return a logical vector (`TRUE`/`FALSE`; see what happens when you execute just `df$JobID == 1`), then passing that logical vector to subset the `Name` vector to those where the logical vector is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` select data for specific `JobID` and extract the unique `Name`.

```
library(dplyr)

FindName <- function(data, id) {
   data %>% filter(JobID == id) %>% pull(Name) %>% unique
}

FindName(df, 1)
#[1] "Ted"  "Bill"

FindName(df, 3)
#[1] "Ox"
```